# If $2$ variables a and b can form 3 combinations such as $a>b$, $a<b$ and $a=b$ then how many combinations can 4 variables form?

Tags: combinatorics

How many unique combinations can $4$ variables have when compared together
For example :

$$a=b>c<d$$

I tried solving it and came to a conclusion that
if $4$ variables can have $6$ unique combination when grouped in a pair and each variable can have $3$ different combination then $4$ variables should have $18$ unique combinations

Comment: Must all the variables be present, or is "$a < c$" a valid combination? Must they be in that order, or is $a < d < c < b$ a valid combination although not equivalent to any formula in $a$,$b$,$c$,$d$ order?

Comment: All variables must be present

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the [Ordered Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number).

Answer (score 2):

Unclear if I am misinterpreting the question. 
Anyway, my take is:

Let $S_k$ denote the computation for Case $k$.

$\underline{\text{Case 1 : All 4 variables distinct}}$

The $4$ variables can be permuted in $4!$ ways.

$$S_1 = 24.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2 : One equal pair, the other 2 variables distinct}}$

There are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways of choosing which two variables are equal.

Once this is done, you (in effect) have $3$ *units*, which can be permuted in $3! = 6$ ways.

$$S_2 = 6 \times 6 = 36.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 3 : Two equal pairs}}$

There are $3$ ways of determining how the two pairs should be formed.

Once this is done, you (in effect) have $2$ *units*, which can be permuted in $2! = 2$ ways.

$$S_3 = 3 \times 2 = 6.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 4 : A triplet}}$

There are $4$ ways of determining which variable is the distinct variable.

Once this is done, you (in effect) have $2$ *units*, which can be permuted in $2! = 2$ ways.

$$S_4 = 4 \times 2 = 8.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 5 : A quartet}}$

There is only $1$ way of forming such a quartet.

$$S_5 = 1.$$

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$S_1 + S_2 + \cdots + S_5 = 24 + 36 + 6 + 8 + 1 = 75.$$

Comment: This doesn't seem to count the given example $a=b>c<d$, which doesn't give order to the units $a=b$ and $d$.

Comment: @aschepler  You are absolutely right.  However, I presumed that that was a typo, on the part of the OP.  At the start of my answer, I indicated that I wasn't sure of the OP's intent.  I was hoping, that if I had misread the OP's intent, he would leave a comment, and I would react.  My answer was motivated by the question's title, re $2$ variables.  Taking what the OP said literally, I couldn't make any sense of how to interpret the question, let alone attack it.  For example, what if $a,b,c,d$ are distinct.  Instead of $24$ permutations, how many should be counted?

Comment: Yes, it's still much too underspecified.